# Spring Migration: Set default Encoding on StandardServletMultipartResolver

Tags: java, spring, migration, multipart

I'm migrating a Spring 5 application to Spring 6. In the old code I was using the `CommonsMultipartResolver` as a `MultipartResolver`-Bean. Since Spring 6 the `CommonsMultipartResolver` is gone and I have to use the `StandardServletMultipartResolver`, but this class does not have a `setDefaultEncoding` method, which was previously used. What's the new recommended way to achieve the same behavior?

I googled but i could only find migration guides for the file-size related methods of the old `CommonsMultipartResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened for me also I have Removed commons-fileupload & commons-io dependency

1 Define the **StandardServletMultipartResolver** bean in your Spring configuration file

```
@Bean 
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() 
{ 
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver(); 
}
```

For parsing multipart request,We need to set a **MultipartConfigElement** in our DispatcherServletregistration :

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(servletContext.getInitParameter(SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("", 50000000, 50000000, 0));
    }
}
```

You can give your MAXSIZE for File Upload